# Getting summary from the merged cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

As I am not familiar to excel and I have been given this task I would like to understand that is it possible to get a summary from the report below.

[image: Example of spreadsheet]

I am easily able to filter the usage result by selected cell color, but I am unable to copy it on a email I get this error below.

[image: Merged cell error]

So I am trying to find a way to get the summary as shown below.

[image: Required output #1]

and
[image: Required output #2]

Or, I don't mind if I get the output as below. with or without tabs

```
Name        Team Group  Expence     Result
Shirin          A       Usage       80.00%
Francis         A       Usage       86.36%

Name        Team Group  Expence     Result
Francis         B       Usage       60.30%
```

Comment: Can you just unmerge the first and second column, and leave it blank for 2 rows?

Comment: The report is very big and i can't do it every day.

Comment: you can just select column a and b, then click on the merge button (which will unmerge all cells)

Answer (score 0):

All You need to do is summary marked red cells addresses by writeing them down by manual typing. When You marked one cell You will see they address even if it merged.

[Example from Office Libre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmukM.png)

Comment: Can you give more information with the Data in OP question?

Comment: @Sam what kind of details do you need. it would be great if you could be more specific.

Comment: Like providing a real solution to OP

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new table in another sheet.

```
      A    |     B      |     C       |    D
=Sheet1!A2 | =Sheet1!B2 | =Sheet1!C4  | =Sheet1!D4
=Sheet1!A5 | =Sheet1!B5 | =Sheet1!C7  | =Sheet1!D7
=Sheet1!A8 | =Sheet1!B8 | =Sheet1!C10 | =Sheet1!D10
```

Assuming your first row is a header, and the data starts at row 2.